# Find all positive integers $a, b$ and $c$ such that $a! + b! = c!$

Tags: combinatorics

How to find all positive integers $a, b$ and $c$ such that $a! + b! = c!$?

So far all I can think of is for when $a = 1, b$ = 1, and $c$ = 2, however I'm struggling to find how I can justify this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math stack exchange!, People will be a lot more encouraged to help you if you show what are your thoughts on this question, i.e. what have you tried, what do you think the answer is and from where is the question.

Comment: Try some larger examples - see if you can figure out *why* this is the only solution. (Hint: Is $100!+99!$ even close to $101!$?)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is a solution where $c=1000$.  Then wlog, $a!\le b!$ so $1000!\le 2×b!$.  But $b<1000$ fails this inequality because $1000!=1000×999!$, and $b\ge 1000$ also fails because $a!$ must be positive.

What is the largest possible value of $c$ that avoids this contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

We may assume that $1 \le a \le b \le c$.
Then we may cancel $a!$ on both sides of $a! + b! = c!$ to get $1+b\cdots(a+1) = c\cdots(a+1)$. Since $c\ge b$, both products are multiples of $b$ and therefore so is $1$. This means that $b=1$, which gives $a=1$ and $c=2$.

Answer (score 1):

a and b are at most c-1.  For that case you need 2(c-1)!=c!=c(c-1)!.  This holds only when c=2, i.e. a=b=1 and c=2 is the only solution.  For any other (a,b,c) a!+b!$\lt$c!.